# How to format input in function

Tags: angular, typescript, format

I would like to create function where input will be formatted from `999999999,99`
to `999 999 999,99`.
Is there any solution or library or I have to write some regex and add spaces after 3 numbers?

I have tried:

```
format() {
    this.form.test.control
      .setValue(formatCurrency(this.form.test.test.control.value, 'pl-PL', 'PLN'));
    let helper: string;
    helper = this.form.test.control.value;
    helper = helper.replace("PLN", "").replace(" ", "").replace(",", ".").replace(String.fromCharCode(160), "");
  }
```

I would like to transform helper to number field. But I am getting problem with replace. It is replaces `.replace(String.fromCharCode(160), "");`only once.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was trying with formatCurrency and next replace chars. I will edit my question